# sql query to download BLOB Data from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a way to load blob data from the table faq_attachment into a directory of my choice using a sql command in the MYSQL Workbench.
If necessary, the name can be composed of
file_id + filename Example: 61_image.png

I am unfortunately not a mysql expert…

[image]

thanks a lot

Comment: There is no way to script that in MySQL Workbench. You can right click on the BLOB fields in the result grid and click on "Save Value To File..." but that will be rather laborious if you have a lot of files to export. If you Google there are various free apps that say they can export from SQL BLOBs to files. Here is a blog post about one - https://www.yohz.com/blogs/tag/extract-blob-to-file/

Comment: Thanks, is there any suggestion how to do the task maybe with a SELECT .... query?

Comment: The result grid shown in your original post is the result of a SELECT query. You need to use something (programming language or app) to run the query and extract the data to write the files to your file system. Unless you are familiar with a programming language I suggest you use one of the free apps designed for.this purpose.

Comment: I have some php scripts created and running that use select queries e.g. CO2 , KW.... values to visualize them in highcharts.

In this specific case I do not know how this query can look in mysql, because php also transmits the query to the mysql database.
The query in this example is : SELECT * FROM faq_attachment where Fax_id = '64'; 

In other words I would need an example for querying the BLOB content in the mysql language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very crude example but it should work. There is no graceful error handling or safety checks. It will overwrite existing files so make sure `$file_path` is writable and empty.

```php
<?php

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$db_name = '';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host";
$user = '';
$password = '';

// the file path must be writable by the current user
$file_path = 'D:\\tmp\\';

// Creates a PDO instance representing a connection to a database
$PDO = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepares and executes an SQL statement and returns a PDOStatement object or false on failure.
$stmt = $PDO->query('SELECT `id`, `filename`, `content_type`, `content` FROM `faq_attachment`', PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// iterates through the returned result set
foreach ($stmt as $file) {

    // prepare filename with full path to write to
    $filename = $file_path . str_replace(' ', '-', "{$file->id}_{$file->filename}");

    // writes the content from the BLOB to the given file
    file_put_contents($filename, $file->content);

}
```

Comment: Thank you that looks like the way I was looking for.
FETCH_OBJ is the core, right ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. I have added some more comments to the code. The PDO::FETCH_OBJ just sets the fetch mode of the returned PDOStatement object. As long as you enter the required details ($db_name, $db_host, $user, $password and $file_path) it should work, assuming you do not hit any size limitations or permissions problems.

Comment: Dear nnichols- Great, have tested your code adapted on my Linux server and the result is brilliant!!! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer if it has provided what you needed. Cheers